# Rails - get the current request's 'URI Pattern'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How do you get the "URI Pattern" (as shown in `rake routes`) for the current HTTP request?

`/blogs/:blog_id/posts/:id`

I'd like to capture performance stats for each route. Need to distinguish between GET /blogs and GET/blogs/5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's done by `Rails.application.routes.router.recognize`. You can use it in a method like this.

```
def this_requests_pattern(request)
  Rails.application.routes.router.recognize(request) do |route|
    return route.path.spec.to_s
  end
end
```